# When to use "connaître" and when to use "savoir"?

Tags: choix-de-mot, rule-of-thumb

Discussing [this question](https://french.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3/policy-on-correcting-peoples-french/12#12) raised a point about when to use *connaître* and when to use *savoir*. The advice given was

> generally speaking, connaître is knowing about a topic whereas savoir
>   is knowing a fact.

Is there a simple rule that can help remember which to use? (E.g. for the abstract "knowing" use X?)

Comment: What's wrong with the simple rule that you quoted yourself?

Comment: The line between topic and fact seemed quite hazy - I was wondering if someone else had some good advice that might help it stick.

Comment: The way I think of it (which could be wrong) is that you can replace "connaître" with "am familiar with", while "savoir" is used in the sense of "I know that [x]" where [x] is some fact.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Unfortunately, there's no rule of thumb: the two verbs have different meanings.

*Savoir* means *to know* something because you have learned about it (e.g. read about it, heard about it). You never use it for a person.

> Je sais que la terre n'est pas plate.
> *(I know the earth is not flat.)*

*Connaître* means *to know about* someone or something because you have met them or experimented it.

> Je connais John.
> *(I know John.)*
>
> Je connais la physique.
> *(I know my physics.)*

Comment: Ainsi que le "je sais nager" (I can swim) où l'anglais n'utilise pas *know* mais rentre pourtant dans le premier cas, étant donné que l'on a appris à nager/marcher/...

Comment: @LudoMC: Exact, mais je pense que c'est un léger abus du verbe *savoir* : on devrait plutôt dire *Je peux nager*.

Comment: Cela mériterait alors une question à part entière car j'ai toujours entendu "je sais nager" et depuis "tout petit" :) La remarque est intéressante car il est vrai que l'on est là dans la capacité physique qui devrait normalement utiliser "pouvoir". Y a-t-il une règle grammaticale là-dessus?

Comment: In local varieties of French, it can differ. E.g. Cajun French where connaître is often used instead of savoir.

Comment: @LudoMC Par rapport à la capacité physique dont tu parles, en reprenant ton exemple, un maitre-nageur avec les deux bras dans le platre ne *peut* pas nager, mais il *sait* toujours nager, il n'a pas oublié. A l'inverse, moi je peux nager (rien ne m'en empêche, c'est en ma puissance), mais je ne sais pas car je n'ai pas appris.

Comment: "savoir" , in this case, means "to know how". "Je sais nager" means "I know how to swim". "Je sais cuisiner" means " I know how to cook".

Comment: Très bonne répons!

Comment: « *Nous n'avons pas besoin de savoir ce que nous n'avons nul besoin de connaître.* » (Auguste Comte) I think this quote is very useful when first approximating the difference. We can conclude from this quote that *connaître* comes first, *savoir* comes second. First one learns to recognise something or look for something in their mind, then they come to know something for certain about that object.

Answer (score 14):

Looking at the headings under *connaître* and *savoir* in the *Petit Robert* is helpful.

*Connaître* is (primarily):

- to have something in mind (the thing can be anything: a concrete object, a person, an abstract concept).
  I know this word. *Je connais ce mot*.
  I know the answer to this question. *Je connais la réponse à cette question*.
  I know Dante's works well. *Je connais bien l'œuvre de Dante*.
  I have known hunger. *J'ai connu la faim*.
- to know a person. The possible connotations are mostly the same as in English.

*Savoir* is (primarily):

- to know a precise fact, i.e. to be aware that this fact is true.
  I know that the sky is blue. *Je sais que le ciel est bleu.*
  I know how to do this. *Je sais comment faire cela.*
  I know who Dante is. *Je sais qui est Dante.*
  I know what hunger is. *Je sais ce que c'est que la faim.*

There are numerous idioms and oddities; ultimately deciding between the two words is one of these matters of usage that only come with practice.

The usage can even vary in space and time. In Belgian French, *savoir* is often used to mean “be able to” (whereas in France *pouvoir* is the normal verb); this usage is rare in France but comes up in a few idioms. As recently as a century ago, *savoir* could be used in sentences like *je sais le latin* (I know Latin, I can speak Latin) which in modern French would sound odd (« *je sais parler latin* », « *je connais le latin* » sound more natural).

Comment: "Je connais parler latin" is utterly wrong, however.

Comment: On préférera un implicite "Je parle latin." même si pour une langue morte ça pourrait sembler étrange.

Answer (score 5):

Maybe some examples will help:

> Est-ce que tu sais quand a eu lieu la révolution française?
>   — Non, je ne connais pas très bien l'histoire.
>
> Je connais cet homme, mais je ne sais pas quel est son métier.
>
> Tu n'as jamais entendu parler de l'Arc de Triomphe? Pourtant, c'est connu!
>
> Est-ce que tu connais le site *WordReference*?
>   — Oui, mais je ne connais pas l'adresse.

Note: in the last exemple, “*je ne sais pas quelle est l'adresse*” is also possible.

Answer (score 5):

Même si la lecture en est assez technique, et non traduite je le crains (c'est une tâche qui dépasse de loin mes talents de traducteur !), on peut se référer à l'*Encyclopédie philosophique universelle* (*Les Notions Philosophiques - tome 1*, Sylvain Auroux, 1998, PUF) pour distinguer **connaître** et **savoir** :

---

> Le terme français *connaissance*, qui remonte au XIIème siècle, est un dérivé du verbe *conoistre*, apparu un siècle plus tôt et qui, à son tour, dérive du latin *cognoscere*. Tant le français *connaissance*, l'allemand *Erkenntnis* et l'anglais *knowledge* que l'anglais et le français *cognition*, comme l'allemand *Kognition*, renvoient, en dernière analyse, à la base indo-européenne *ĝenē-*, *genō-* au sens d'« être mentalement capable ». C'est de cette racine que sont également dérivés en grec les formes se rattachant au verbe *gignōskō*. **Tandis que l'anglais organise le champ sémantique de l'action cognitive et de son résultat à partir de *to know*, l'allemand recourt à la dualité *(er-)kennen/wissen* et le français à celle de *connaître/savoir***. Le grec (*oída*, *epístamai*, *gignōskō*) et le latin (*scire*, *noscere*, *cognoscere*) montrent encore une plus grande diversité lexicale. Le latin *cognoscere* a le même sens que la forme sans préfixe *noscere*, dont le présent (*nosco*) signifie « j'apprends à connaître » et le parfait (*novi*) « j'ai appris, je sais ». L'acception de « connaissance en train de se faire » (le connaître) et celle de « connaissance faite » (concept ou idée) se retrouvent dans le substantif *notio* qui dérive du participe *notus*, « connu », et qui se trouve à l'origine du concept de « notion » dans la plupart des langues européennes modernes. Bien que l'espagnol *conocimiento*, l'italien *conoscimento* et le portugais *conhecimento* aient la signification de l'acte de connaître et de la faculté cognitive, ils ont pris aussi — principalement au pluriel — le sens de ce qu'on connait pour l'avoir appris. Parallèlement, le français *connaissance* peut signifier soit l'acte de présentation à l'esprit d'un objet et/ou sa pénétration intellectuelle, soit la faculté qui réalise cet acte, soit l'idée ou notion d'un objet comme résultat du processus cognitif. **Bien que dans la langue courante, « connaissance » et « savoir » soient souvent utilisés indistinctement, les termes ne sont pas interchangeables**, comme le montre tout essai de traduction du terme hégélien *das absolute Wissen*. Stricto sensu on peut concevoir l'absolu d'un *savoir* absolu réfléchi et total des conditions dialectiques qui l'ont mené à son propre achèvement, mais non pas une *connaissance* absolue, laquelle comporte en dernière analyse une *contradictio in adjecto*, étant donné que l'action de connaître — indéfectiblement liée à la finitude de l'action temporelle du sujet qui la réalise — ne peut en tant que telle aspirer à nommer ni la compréhension achevée de l'absolu, ni même l'intelligence absolue d'une chose finie. A la rigueur, c'est seulement le savoir en tant que terme et résultat clôturant le processus — temporel et donc fini — de connaissance qui peut être qualifié, dans certaines circonstances, d'*absolu*. Tenant compte de cette distinction, on comprend que le Dieu de l'onto-théologie (qui ne peut être pensé comme soumis aux conditions de la temporalité) ne soit pas capable de connaître. S'il existait, cependant, il serait tenu de tout savoir.

Comment: Merci! C'est la réponse que je cherchais quand je posai une autre question, ne **sachant** pas qu'il y avait déjà une question trop proche de la même topique.

Comment: Il est surprenant de voir les grandes difficultés qu'éprouvent les philosophes lorsque ce qu'ils ont à dire n'est pas compris dans les mots du langage ou que les artefacts de l'imagination ne peuvent appréhender (le mental ne peut guérir le mental, l’œil ne peut se regarder lui-même), avec des conclusions incertaines car soumise à un ‘si’. On est seul à pouvoir *connaître l'indicible* (expériences extrêmes, mystiques, purement sensorielles, ..) sans pouvoir ni *savoir* y mettre des mots. Ce qu'un robot ne peut connaître, c'est l'espace vital, le *vide*  oriental, là où le corps sensible évolue

Answer (score 5):

I good rule of thumb that I've learned in my college french class is that you use *connaître* as *connaître + [article + noun]/proper name*

> Je connais John.
>   Je connais la physique.
>   Je connais la chose dont tu parles.

while *savoir* is used if what follows is an infinitive, conjunction, or question word.

> Je sais conduire.
>   Je sais que tu es fatigué.
>   Je sais où ça s'est passé. *(en revanche: je connais l'endroit où ça s'est passé)*

These aren't rules, but rather guidelines. There are cases where these won't hold (for example, I *believe* (but someone correct me if I'm wrong) that *je connais le français* means I'm aware of the existence of the french language, but I don't necessarily know how to speak it, while *je sais le français* means you an intimate knowledge of the language and implies you most likely speak it), but I don't know of any rules or generalization to explain them.

Answer (score 3):

**Savoir vs Connaître**

Both mean "to know" but **Connaître** is used basically **for specific place or a person.**[image]

Answer (score 2):

Une astuce consiste à rattacher

- *savoir* à l'objectivité et,
- *connaître* à la subjectivité.

Ligne générale :

- on sait des choses avec le mental ;
- on connaît par les sens et l'expérience.

> On *sait* calculer, on *connaît* la science des mathématiques.
>  On *sait* que
>   La Tour Eiffel existe, on la *connaît* après l'avoir visité,

Deux expressions familières :

- « On sait des tas de choses », parce que l'on *croit* qu'elles existent, alors qu'elle ne sont que dans notre imaginaire, à l'intérieur de notre boite crânienne,
- « On connaît son monde », pour dire que l'on est pas dupe de la réalité, que l'on a déjà éprouvé le monde.

*Corrections, suite aux remarques*

On peut aussi rattacher : *Savoir* + verbe,  *Connaître* + substantif :

- « On sait nager », car on maîtrise *la technique*, mais on n'agit pas forcément ; c'est une connaissance objective,
- « On connaît la nage indienne » car on a assimilé la particularité (on pourrait dire l'*art*) de cette nage, que l'on peut pratiquer à volonté.

> On *connaît* la Tour Eiffel parce qu'on en a entendu parler, sans *savoir* comment y aller.

Comment: Je ne vois pas ce que tu veux dire avec « on connaît la natation ». Ce n'est pas une expression très courante. Elle peut vouloir dire qu'on a entendu parler de la natation, ou éventuellement (mais il faut un contexte approprié) que le sujet est compétent en natation, qu'il *s'y connaît* en natation. Pour la tour Eiffel, on aussi peut dire qu'on la *connaît* parce qu'on en a entendu parler, il faut le contexte pour clarifier.

Comment: @Gilles En effet, en seconde lecture l'exemple retenu ne convenait pas. J'ai plutôt mis en exergue les liaisons verbe/substantif, plutôt que science/art. J'ai repris votre remarque sur la tour Eiffel, qui s'insère bien dans le dernier §, alors quelle  n'était pas dans le contexte du § "Ligne générale".

Answer (score 1):

**Savoir**, with a **noun** or **pronoun** object or **introducing a clause** means know in the sense of being **aware of, having learnt, or having been informed about**.

> Je sais la réponse.
>
> Il savait sa leçon.
>
> Savez-vous son nom ?
>
> Je sais comment le faire.
>
> Savez-vous l'heure du train ?
>
> Elle ne savait pas s'il viendrait.
>
> On sait qu'elle est partie pendant la nuit.
>
> Je n'ai su que dire. Je n'ai pas su quoi dire.

---

**Savoir** governing an **infinitif**, has the sense of know how to (can) and its usage must be distinguished from **pouvoir** which means **can** in the sense of (being) **physically able to**. Cf.

> Elle ne sait pas conduire. (She cannot drive = She doesn't know to drive.)
>
> Elle ne peut pas conduire. (She cannot drive (because of physical inability.)

---

In carefully French, the **conditional of savoir**, in the **negative**, but without **pas**, may be used to render the negative present tense of pouvoir.

> Je ne saurais l'expliquer. I cannot account for it.

---

**Connaitre** on the other hand, means **know** in the sense of **being familiar with, having an understanding of**.

> Il connait le droit, l'espagnol.
>
> Je connais cet homme, cette ville, le chemin, le bonheur.

Source:
[A French Reference Grammar](https://www.amazon.fr/French-Reference-Grammar-H-Ferrar/dp/0199120331)

Comment: *Je connais la réponse* is [more common](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=je+connais+la+r%C3%A9ponse%2C+je+sais+la+r%C3%A9ponse&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=fr-2019&smoothing=3) than *je sais la réponse*.

Answer (score 0):

En général, les réponses antérieures sont exactes, et l'on doit dire "mon voisin connaît - et non connait - un Allemand qui sait le polonais".

Mais regardez les définitions et citations du Littré, de grands auteurs classiques ont écrit exactement l'inverse, du genre "il sait un tailleur qui connaît son métier", "il connaît un peu d'espagnol".

Comment: Je n'ai pas retrouvé la citation du *tailleur* (ni à *métier*, ni à *connaître*), mais "Il *connaît* un tailleur qui *connaît* son métier" n'est pas en usage en littérature où la répétition est proscrite (sauf pour des effets de style). Êtes-vous sûr qu'il ne s'agit pas de "Il connaît un peu **l**'espagnol" ?

Comment: En français moderne, le voisin *parle* polonais, ou *sait parler* polonais, ou éventuellement *connaît le polonais* (ça passe mieux dans des expressions comme « connaît un peu de polonais »). Au moins en France, on ne dit plus « sait le polonais » (mais on le disait il y a un siècle ou deux). On ne dit plus non plus « il sait un tailleur... », ça ne passe vraiment pas.