# Quelle est la différence entre "connaître" et "savoir"?

Tags: choix-de-mot, comparaison-de-langues

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Connaître and savoir](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/39/connaitre-and-savoir)

Je sais qu'il y a une telle différence en autres langues, par exemple "tuntea" et "tietää" en finnois, et "känna" et "veta" en suédois, mais en anglais il n'y a qu'un seul verbe, "know" pour les deux sens.

Mais la différence est plus subtile qu'elle m'a paru.  On parle de "l'arbre de la connaissance du bien et du mal" en français, mais en finnois et en suédois on parle de l'arbre de la connaissance comme de *savoir* le bien et le mal.

En effet, les mots "connaître" et "know" sont de la même ancienne origine.

Je pense qu'il y a peu de différence entre "savoir quelque fait" et "connaître la vérité de quelque fait".

Alors, y a-t-il des cas où on peut utiliser pareillement "connaître" ou "savoir"?  Je suis encore un peu confondu de ces deux verbes.

Comment: Question intéressante, peut-être plus philosophique que linguistique, mais déjà en partie traitée [ici](http://french.stackexchange.com/questions/39/connaitre-and-savoir).

Comment: Par contre tu peux éditer la question doublon, ajouter la tienne en guise de traduction et enrichir la version anglaise si tu te sens motivé :)