# Regarding how to use the verb "connaître"

Tags: vocabulaire, expressions, pronoms, verbes

> Je ne **te connaissais** pas **ce penchant** pour l'art.
>
> I didn’t know you had a passion for art.

I’ve just heard a native French speaker say this sentence. Given how the English translation goes, I’m tempted to put in some word like "**avoir**" between "connaissais" and "ce penchant". Is it wrong to change the sentence construction given above?

---

It would be easy to understand if the sentence took the more straightforward form:

> Je ne **connaissais** pas **ton penchant** pour l'art.

---

What also has me puzzled is, how would you change the sentence if you swapped "te" with a woman’s name "Sherry"? Should I say:

> Je ne connaissais pas **Sherry** ce penchant pour l'art.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Le seul emploi intransitif de *connaitre* que je connaisse est dans l'expression « connaitre quelque chose à quelqu'un » qui veut dire qu'on **sait** que ce quelqu'un **a** quelque chose.
Le complément d'objet direct de *connaitre* est *le penchant*. Donc on peut dire :

> Je ne te connaissais pas ce penchant pour l'art.

On peut introduire le verbe *avoir* effectivement. On peut en quelque sorte dire que *le penchant* « est à » (dans le sens de « appartient à ») *te*. Et donc le verbe *avoir* sert de lien entre *te* et *le penchant*.  Mais celui qui connait reste *je*. On va donc avoir une phrase constituée de deux propositions :

1- Je ne connaissais pas un fait sur toi
 2-  tu as un penchant pour l'art

> Je ne savais pas que tu avais ce penchant pour l'art.

*Te* peut être remplacé par n'importe quel nom de personne :

> Je ne savais pas que Sherry avait ce penchant pour l'art.

Si on garde l'expression « connaitre quelque chose à quelqu'un » en utilisant 
le nom de la personne (et non un pronom personnel) on introduit la personne avec la préposition *à* :

> Je ne connaissais pas ce penchant pour l'art à Sherry.
>   Je ne connaissais pas à Sherry ce penchant pour l'art.

À voir en complément sur French Language : [When to use connaître and when to use savoir?](https://french.stackexchange.com/q/39/358)

Comment: To Laure: @Laure So if I stick to using "connaître", is it correct to say "Je ne connaissais pas ce penchant pour l'art **à Sherry**?" or "Je ne connaissais pas ce penchant pour l'art **chez Sherry**?" Merci.

Comment: @LUNA My answer was lacking and I was rewriting (rather than editing!) my answer to insist more on this peculiar construction. Your grasp of the language is excellent, I feel you can cope with answers in French. I'll write in English if you ask of course.

Comment: @LUNA I would not use *chez* but I cannot say definitely say it would be not be used.

Comment: To Laure: @Laure      {chez} Oh, I see. I think I can now smoothly grasp 95% of the explanations written in French, and as for the remaining 5%, I can always consult dictionaries and such, so I now feel completely confortable with the reading aspect of French. My speaking/writing skills still have a lot of catching up to do, though!

Comment: We are in the saaaame boat LUNA. Same boat.