# Faut-il utiliser "connaître" ou "savoir" dans cette phrase ?

Tags: grammaire, choix-de-mot

Pourriez-vous me dire si cette phrase est correcte :

> Je pense que mes amis me prendraient pour une folle s'ils connaissaient cette histoire.

Est-ce que ce sera mieux d'utiliser le verbe "savoir" au lieu de "connaître" ici ?

Comment: *Ils savaient cette histoire* ne se dit plus aujourd'hui. Ce sera toujours *ils connaissaient* ou *ils étaient au courant de cette histoire*. Voir [When to use "connaître" and when to use "savoir"?](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/39/when-to-use-conna%c3%aetre-and-when-to-use-savoir)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dans cette phrase, le verbe *connaître* est un raccourci à "avoir connaissance de". La phrase complète serait dans ce cas :

> Je pense que mes amis me prendraient pour une folle s'ils avaient connaissance de cette histoire.

Le verbe *savoir*, quant à lui, est différent. Savoir une histoire, c'est l'avoir apprise.

De plus, quand bien même les deux pourraient se dire, il est préférable d'utiliser ici le verbe *connaître*, qui est beaucoup plus utilisé de nos jours.